# Mingw32 at win7x64:Qt 5.3.0 x86 compilation: wrong path fed to uic.exe

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, mingw, qmake

I am trying to compile current "stable" build I pulled from Qt git. The problem is when it tries to use uic (UI compiler) my path variable gets mangled in some way and it can't find icu libraries, which are on the path, but if I drop the libraries in the same directory as uic it works, but this isn't really a solution.

My path variable:

```
%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;%systemroot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;%systemroot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;I:\miktex\miktex\bin;E:\Program Files\doxygen\bin;E:\Python27;E:\icu\lib;E:\strawberry\c\bin;E:\strawberry\perl\site\bin;E:\strawberry\perl\bin;E:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;
```

The relevant output from the mingw32-make is

```
mingw32-make[3]: Entering directory 'e:/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets'
mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug all
mingw32-make[4]: Entering directory 'e:/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets'
PATH=e:/qt5/qtbase/lib${PATH:+:$PATH} e:/qt5/qtbase/bin/uic.exe dialogs/qfiledialog.ui -o .uic/ui_qfiledialog.h
Makefile.Debug:2443: recipe for target '.uic/ui_qfiledialog.h' failed
mingw32-make[4]: Leaving directory 'e:/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets'
Makefile:38: recipe for target 'debug-all' failed
mingw32-make[3]: Leaving directory 'e:/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets'
Makefile:437: recipe for target 'sub-widgets-make_first' failed
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'e:/qt5/qtbase/src'
Makefile:41: recipe for target 'sub-src-make_first' failed
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'e:/qt5/qtbase'
Makefile:64: recipe for target 'module-qtbase-make_first' failed
```

The part about `PATH=e:/qt5/qtbase/lib${PATH:+:$PATH}` looks awfully suspicious to me, sadly I know little about makefiles and this particular syntax.

Comment: Yeah, that line looks odd. Where did you get your copy of MinGW from? I just ran it using the copy that came with Qt itself (which I believe is from http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/files/host-windows/releases/4.8.0/32-bit/), and I got these instead: `mingw32-make[4]: Entering directory 'C:/Qt/git/5.x.y/qtbase/src/widgets'
(set PATH=C:\Qt\git\5.x.y\qtbase\lib;%PATH:)=^)%) & C:\Qt\git\5.x.y\qtbase\bin\uic.exe dialogs\qfiledialog.ui -o .uic\ui_qfiledialog.h`. Also, I used the Windows command prompt, not MSYS.

Comment: any solutions for this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

I had basically the same problem crop up - the invocation of uic.exe would fail silently and the build recipe would fail. Turned out that make was getting confused by spaces in my path. Going to the System control panel to add double quotes at the beginning and end of the system path, if they are not present, appears to fix the problem. My user path was empty (just a pair of quotes), but it might be necessary to add quotes around that too if not already there.

Earlier I also solved the problem by going to the System control panel to get the default path, stripping out the entries with spaces, then running the following in PowerShell:

```
PS C:\Qt\build\5.4.1> $env:Path="C:\Perl64\site\bin;C:\Perl64\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;C:\mingw-w64\i686-4.9.2-posix-dwarf-rt_v4-rev2\mingw32\bin"
PS C:\Qt\build\5.4.1> mingw32-make -j
```

The build then proceeded normally. BTW, the first line only sets the path for the current PowerShell session, doesn't muck with the path set in the registry.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not at all an expert/authority on this, but I feel this is happening because you have 32 bit MINGW installed on a 64 Bit Windows 7.

Another issue - I do not see e:/qt5/qtbase/ in the path.

As stated earlier I could be very wrong.

Comment: 32-bit MinGW is perfectly functional on 64-bit Windows. The Qt source directory does not need to be in the PATH.

Comment: I have an official distribution of mingw32, and yes, it doesn't require qtbase to be on path. Sadly I don't really have time right now to try and dig for the problem. So I found an unofficial builds with mingw version I need. Should anyone need a Qt with mingw for 32bit windows, check out http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/files/external-binary-packages/Qt-Builds/